# Rails 5 submit data through a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, erb, has-many-through, link-to

I would like to submit information from my views using a link_to orders controller which I'm not sure how to code.

**My models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :stocks, through: :orders
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

**The way to make orders from the rails console is**

```
order = Order.new
user = User.last
stock = Stock.last
final = user.orders.create(user_id: user.id, stock_id: stock.id)
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admins
  get '/history', to: 'orders#history'

  post '/stocks/:id/', to: 'stocks#order', as: 'order_stock'

  resources :stocks
  root 'stocks#index'
end
```

I would like to have a single link from
**app/views/stocks/show**
to submit orders

Help with the link and controller actions would very appreciate it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: you can use cocoon gem or if you prefer you can use ryan bates nested model form (you can learn from this link http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)

Comment: I would rather do it without extra gems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are about to `create` a new `order` object; so using `POST` as a HTTP method would sound more appropriate. So,

```
link_to "Order Now!", order_stock_path(params[:id]), method: :post
```

should work I guess.

[See this for more info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

In stocks_controller

```
def order
  stock = current_user.stocks.find(params[:id])
  stock.order.create
  redirect_to stock_path(params[:id]), notice: 'Order created'
end
```

It should look somewhat this

**Note**: Rails will send an AJAX POST call to the controller in this case; on success it will redirect accordingly. AJAX code will be embedded near the code to the link. See in the browser your self.

Comment: undefined method `order_stock_path' for #<#<Class:0x005634b52b2010>:0x007f26d6312e88>
Did you mean?  edit_stock_path

Comment: Don't I need a new route for this?

Comment: I added  this route 
 post '/stocks/:id/', to: 'stocks#order', as: 'order_stock'
And now getting 
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ')' r).permit(:user_id, stock_id:) ^

Comment: Try instead `:stock_id`.

Comment: That didn't work. Basically, I need to pass both ids